# Sum identity over the reciprocal of central binomial coefficients using their partial fraction decompositions.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, euler-sums

Prove
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^k\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac12 {_{k+1}F_k}\left(\underbrace{1,\dots,1}_{k+1};\frac32,\underbrace{2,\dots,2}_{k-1};\frac14\right)$$

where ${_m F_n}$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html) (which is referenced in [equation 44](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html)) using the partial fraction decomposition of the reciprocal binomial:
$$\frac{1}{\binom{z}{n}} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-i}\binom{n}{i}\frac{n-i}{z-i}$$

replacing $z$ with $2n$. Or

$$\frac{1}{\binom{z+n}{n}} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i-1}\binom{n}{i}\frac{i}{z+i}$$

replacing $z$ with $n$.  The above identities are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Partial_fraction_decomposition).

My motivation is, by learning how to do this, to see if the first sum can be generalized to non-central binomial coefficients using the partial fraction decomposition formula.